# IIS 7.5 Installation required only once if IIS is disable

Tags: wix, iis-7.5, wix3.5

Hi i am using the below code to enable the IIS 7.5 in windows 7 . its working fine. but problem is every time when is run the setup (.MSi) IIS installs and uninstall time also its enable the IIS7.5 , how to put a condition to check if iis7.5 is disable then i want to install IIS. i am using wix3.5

Please help me.

```
 <CustomAction Id="InstallIISCA" PatchUninstall="no" Return="check" Property="INSTALLIISPROP" Execute="oncePerProcess" HideTarget="yes" Impersonate="yes"
       ExeCommand=" /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole "/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallIISCA" Before="ConfigureIIs" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<Property Id="INSTALLIISPROP" Value="dism.exe"></Property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple conditions that limit when the custom action will run. To only run your IIS check at install time, change your Custom element to this:

```
  <Custom Action="InstallIISCA" Before="ConfigureIIs">
    Not Installed
  </Custom>
```

Your description has a few run-on sentences about the conditions. I think you are also asking for a condition to not do the install if IIS is enabled (? maybe you mean installed ?). To do this, first set a property for that condition (here, checking the version of IIS to determine if its installed)

```
  <Property Id="IIS_MAJOR_VERSION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="CheckIISVersion" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" Name="MajorVersion" Type="raw" />
  </Property>
```

And then include the property in the custom action condition:

```
  <Custom Action="InstallIISCA" Before="ConfigureIIs">
    Not Installed AND IIS_MAJOR_VERSION
  </Custom>
```

And guessing that you already have some condition for the "ConfigureIIS" action, so its not unnecesarily run.